# Spring MVC - Binding Blank Form Values to Primitive Bean Fields

Tags: forms, spring, model-view-controller, binding, javabeans

I've seen several questions that are similar, but I have yet to find an answer that solves this problem. I have a Spring MVC form that is backed by a command object with a primitive property:

```
public class MyBean {
  private int counter;

  public int getCounter() {
    return counter;
  }

  public void setCounter( int counter ) {
    this.counter = counter;
  }
}
```

In the JSP form, I have (abbreviated for clarity):

```
<form:form action="count.do">
  <form:input id="counter" path="counter"/>
</form:form>
```

Now, as long as there is a valid number value in the "counter" input field, everything works as expected, but if the field is blank, then I get a form validation error:

```
org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors Field error in object 'MyBean' on field 'counter': rejected value []; codes [methodInvocation.MyBean.counter,methodInvocation.counter,methodInvocation.float,methodInvocation]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [MyBean.counter,counter]; arguments []; default message [counter]]; default message [Property 'counter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException]
```

I've tried creating a custom property editor to accept null values (initializing it in initBinder() ), but this only works if I create a non-primitive set of wrapper accessors:

```
binder.registerCustomEditor( Integer.class, new CustomNumberEditor(Integer.class, true) );
```

So, is there a way to bind a field on the form to a primitive type without creating the non-primitive wrappers, and still handle blank values (I'd like to set them to 0 rather than erroring out)? If so, would you mind posting a simple example?

Many thanks,
Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never tryed it but try to register the Editor for `int.class` (this realy works).

But because the an `int` can not handle `null` `new CustomNumberEditor(Integer.class, true)` will not work.

So you need your own Number Editor that returns for example `0` is not value is defined.

```
binder.registerCustomEditor( int.class,
     new MyNumberEditorThatConvertsNullToZero() );
```